# Accessing X server remotely

Tags: xorg

I've a machine M and I ssh to it remotely. If I run `xclock` it responds with error `Error: can't open display:`. How can I access the display, so that apps I run show up on the physical screen of the machine I logged into? I know I can use xvfb to create a virtual screen, but is there a way to remotely access the physical one?

Comment: Have you tried "DISPLAY=:0 xclock"?

Comment: @skrblr: Can't open display 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Remote Desktop software](http://www.mynitor.com/2010/02/07/15-remote-desktop-solutions-for-linux/), they can see the apps in your main screen, and are easy to set up and run.

Comment: I understand I can use VNC. Is there a way to do what I described? SSH, then run xclock so it shows on the physical screen?

Comment: @zzz The method is too old, better use VNC.

Comment: tunnel VNC through ssh, it is too vulnerable to be used on its own.

Comment: or through a VPN